# Select list of columns from a data frame using dplyr and select_()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use the following function to extract some columns from a data frame:

```
library('dplyr')
desired_columns = c(
  'a',
  'b',
  'c')
extract_columns <- function(data) {
  extracted_data <- data %>%
    select_(desired_columns)
  return(extracted_data)
}
```

But when I try it, I don't get what I expect:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=1:5, c=1:5, d=1:5)
> df
  a b c d
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5
> extract_columns(df)
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

I seem to be only getting the first column and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. How can I get all the requested columns?

Comment: This is total nonsense IMO, why would you create such complicated function with `dplyr`? How is just `df[desired_columns]` any worse? This is the most basic subsetting operation in R.

Comment: This is a minimal snippet I constructed for this question but the essence of the question, how to use select_() with a list of columns is really the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are just missing the `.dots` argument in `select_`:

```
extract_columns <- function(data) {
    extracted_data <- data %>%
        select_(.dots = desired_columns)
    return(extracted_data)
}

extract_columns(df)
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 4):

A tibble is the tidyverse/dplyr version of a dataframe. Since select() is a dplyr function, you can convert your dataframe to a tibble and use select directly with a list of variables to return another tibble.

```
df = data.frame(a=1:5, b=1:5, c=1:5, d=1:5)
desired_columns = c( 'a', 'b', 'c')
df %>% as_tibble() %>% select(desired_columns)
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you have to use .dots parameter to pass the vector (or list):

`select_(.dots = desired_columns)`

It seems that it has something to do with the laziness.