# How to index character vector in file.path in R

Tags: r

If I do:

```
file.path("", "a", "b", "c.txt")
[1] "/a/b/c.txt"
```

I got the correct file path, but if I do this way:

```
cc<-c("", "a", "b", "c.txt")
file.path(cc)
[1] ""      "a"     "b"     "c.txt"
```

It seems incorrect. I am wondering how to index `cc` in `file.path()`?

Comment: `do.call('file.path', as.list(cc))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you could call this a *list* of arguments rather than just a single one. For example, you can access each element of the dots:

```
f <- function(...) {
  list(one = ..1,
       three = ..3,
       four = ..4,
       two = ..2)
}
f(1, 2, 3, 4)

# $one
# [1] 1
# 
# $three
# [1] 3
# 
# $four
# [1] 4
# 
# $two
# [1] 2
```

But what you really want to do is pass each as individual arguments. So in this case, you need to either do that explicitly (lots of typing) or use `do.call` which allows you to pass a list of parameters to functions

```
cc <- c("", "a", "b", "c.txt")
do.call('file.path', as.list(cc))
# [1] "/a/b/c.txt"
```

`file.path` is nice in that it only has two arguments, one of which you don't need to change but if you *did* you could do

```
do.call('file.path', c(as.list(cc), fsep = '/xx/'))
# [1] "/xx/a/xx/b/xx/c.txt"
```

so in this case you need to pass a *named* list to the function to match each argument

A side note which I have come across, something like

```
do.call('base::mean', list(1:4))
# Error in do.call("base::mean", list(1:4)) : 
#   could not find function "base::mean"
```

won't work if you need to specify a function in a particular package. You either need to do

```
f <- base:::mean; do.call('f', list(1:4))
# [1] 2.5
```

or just

```
do.call(base::mean, list(1:4))
# [1] 2.5
```

Comment: Interestingly, `do.call(base::"mean", list(1:4))` works, but hopefully no one would ever do that.

Comment: `do.call` does not expect to parse its first argument, but if it first gets evaluated to a function-name it will accept it since it does non-standard evaluation.

Comment: @BondedDust I see.. I thought parsing would be "safer" in the same way that `library('x')` is "safer" than `library(x)`

Comment: But `base::mean` is not the name of a function. It fails the `is.name('base::mean')`-test

Comment: oh I see what you mean

Answer (score 6):

I was about to post the same as rawr's accepted answer/comment (so decided to add a bit more after waiting for him to post an answer and then giving up waiting although I see he now does have an answer):

```
do.call('file.path', as.list(cc))
```

Learning to use `as.list` and `do.call` was one of those lessons I learned several years down the road to my current perpetual intermediate R mastery. The reason that rawr's answer works is that the arguments to `file.path` need to come to the args component of the function as a list. The reason that simply wrapping them with `list()`, e.g `file.path(list(cc))`, fails is that the result is a list of length one, whereas the `as.list` function creates a list of length-4. The reason using `file.path(as.list(cc))` also fails is that the parser still loops over that argument as a single vector.

Sometimes `do.call` is the only way to build a function `call` when the argument values are going to be supplied to a `...` (dots) component of a function but exist in some other data-object. If passing to a function with named arguments one can use either lists or pairlists:

```
> dd <- list(from=1, to=2)
> seq(dd)
[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `paste` with `collapse="/"` instead.
So with:

```
cc <- c("", "a", "b", "c.txt")
```

You get:

```
R> paste(cc, collapse="/")
[1] "/a/b/c.txt"
```

Comment: The reason I use file.path() is to avoid using paste().

Comment: file.path() can recognize the difference between platforms like windows and mac.

Comment: Okay, I see. Then rawr's comment above is a much better solution.

Comment: @rawr answer the q with your comment then. Before someone will post a `dplyr` solution.

Comment: @rawr I'll leave you post as an answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg ha! for accessing those deep files 10M directories deep I'm sure that would be super quick

Comment: @rawr if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31592139/select-list-of-columns-from-a-data-frame-using-dplyr-and-select) is considered a legit `dplyr` Q/A, then everything is.